# in angular-ui-bootstrap (v.0.10.0) Datepicker - how do i disable single day(s) by date (or array of dates)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've searched everywhere for longer than i would care to admit, and can not find an answer to this question. the documentation here - http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker - says...

```
date-disabled (date, mode)
```

(Default: null) : An optional expression to disable visible options based on passing date and current mode (day|month|year).

---

and in the HTML markup all of the examples show this in the code as an attribute on the input...

```
date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
```

i need to know what to do in my JavaScript to get this actually functioning. an example for a single day and an example for passing an array of dates would be greatly appreciated.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The markup of

```
date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
```

means that in your scope you would need to have a function named `disabed` that accepts two arguments, `date` and `mode`, which you would use to determine if that date should be disabled.

Here is a clearer example for you.  Make the markup be

```
date-disabled="shouldDateBeDisabled(date, mode)"
```

Then in your Controller you would need to attach a function named `shouldDateBeDisabled` to the `$scope` where you would put your logic.

```
var datesAreEqual = function(date1,date2) {...};
var dateIsInArray = function(date,arrayOfDates) {...};
var someSingleDateToDisable = ...;
var arrayOfDatesToDisable = [...];
$scope.shouldDateBeDisabled = function(date, mode) {
  // your own logic to determine if a date should be disabled
  if (datesAreEqual(date,someSingleDateToDisable) {
    return true;
  }

  if (dateIsInArray(date,arrayOfDatesToDisable) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement in my project to enable days by giving an array of date objects, i have over ridden the default controller in my project.

This is what i did

In **"controller('DatepickerController')"** under **module('ui.bootstrap.datepicker')** 
i have added config and a method

```
this.enabledDays = getValue($attrs.enabledDays, dtConfig.enabledDays);

this.toBeDisabled = function (date, mode) {
            var currentMode = this.modes[mode || 0];
            var flag = false;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.enabledDays.length; i++) {
                if (!currentMode.compare(date, this.enabledDays[i])) {
                    flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return flag;
        }
```

then i changed the following predefined method

```
this.isDisabled = function (date, mode) {

        var currentMode = this.modes[mode || 0];

        return ((this.enabledDays && !this.toBeDisabled(date, mode)) ||
            (this.minDate && currentMode.compare(date, this.minDate) < 0) ||
            (this.maxDate && currentMode.compare(date, this.maxDate) > 0) ||
            ($scope.dateDisabled && $scope.dateDisabled({date: date, mode: currentMode.name})));
    };
```

And in the link function under this directive `directive('datepicker', ...`

I added

```
var enabledDays = datepickerConfig.enabledDays;
    if (attrs.enabledDays) {
                        scope.$parent.$watch($parse(attrs.enabledDays), function (value) {
                            enabledDays = value ? value : null;
                            datepickerCtrl.enabledDays = enabledDays;
                            refill();
                        });
                    }
```

And in the "scope.move" function inside the link function, i added

```
  if (typeof datepickerCtrl.onChange != "undefined") {
        datepickerCtrl.onChange(selected);
  }
```

as you can see below

```
scope.move = function (direction) {
                    var step = datepickerCtrl.modes[mode].step;
                    selected.setMonth(selected.getMonth() + direction * (step.months || 0));
                    selected.setFullYear(selected.getFullYear() + direction * (step.years || 0));
                    if (typeof datepickerCtrl.onChange != "undefined") {
                        datepickerCtrl.onChange(selected);
                    }
                    refill();
                };
```

Now the datepicker is modified

In the HTML markup

```
<datepicker enabled-days="enabledDays" datepickerConfig="datepickerOptions"></datepicker>
```

where "enabledDays" is an array you can define in the scope

Worked well for me without any problems yet

Hope this helps you :)